# How to implement a function to select items only of specific types?

Tags: c#, oop, design-patterns, builder, fluent

#### Context

I have a `Question` class. It has three subclasses:

- `ChoiceQuestion`
- `ShortTextQuestion`
- `LongTextQuestion`

I have a `Repository` class which has an `IEnumerable<Question>`.

---

#### Code

*Question class hierarchy and container class Repository*:

```
class Question {}
class ChoiceQuestion : Question {}

class ShortTextQuestion : Question {}

class LongTextQuestion : Question {}

class Repository
{
    IEnumerable<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

---

#### Problem

I want to pick few questions for a `Questionnaire` from these repositories.

I have an `IQuestionnaireBuilder` which has an `AddSource()` method that helps configure which repository to pick questions from and how to pick them. I have the `QuestionnaireSource` class which holds this configuration.

Currently, I am able to specify, which repository to pick from, how many questions to pick of each difficulty. I want to specify that it should only pick questions which are of specific subtypes.

For instance, the questions to be picked must be either `ChoiceQuestion` or `ShortTextQuestion`. I have come across `System.Type`, but I want to restrict the types such that they must derive from `Question`.

---

#### Code

*IQuestionnaireBuilder*

```
interface IQuestionnaireBuilder
{
    IQuestionnaireBuilder AddSource(Action<QuestionnaireSource> source);
}
```

*QuestionnaireSource*

```
class QuestionnaireSource
{
    public Repository Repository { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<QuestionDifficulty, int> { get; set; }
    
    // <Property/method to configure which subclasses to include, they must derive from Question>
}
```

*QuestionDifficulty*

```
enum QuestionDifficulty
{ Easy, Medium, Hard }
```

```
    IQuestionnaireBuilder builder = new QuestionnaireBuilder();
    
    Repository repo1 = someExternalProvider.GetRepo(1);
    Repository repo2 = someExternalProvider.GetRepo(2);
    builder
        .AddSource(source => {
            source.Repository = repo1;
            source.Count[QuestionDifficulty.Easy] = 10;
            source.Count[QuestionDifficulty.Medium] = 7;
            source.Count[QuestionDifficulty.Hard] =  3;
            source.PickOnlySpecificSubclassesOfQuestion() // how to implement this? 
       })
       .AddSource(source => {
            source.Repository = repo2;
            source.Count[QuestionDifficulty.Easy] = 30;
            source.Count[QuestionDifficulty.Medium] = 15;
            source.Count[QuestionDifficulty.Hard] =  5;
            source.PickOnlySpecificSubclassesOfQuestion() // how to implement this? 
       })
```

In the above snippet, how do I implement the `PickOnlySpecificSubclassesOfQuestion()` part?

Comment: Did you try using the `OfType` method? [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.oftype?view=net-5.0]

Comment: This question is being discussed on [Meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/409008).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I've done it using delegates. I added a `Filter` property to `QuestionnaireSource` of type `System.Predicate<T>`. [`System.Predicate<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.predicate-1?view=net-5.0) is a delegate defined as follows:

```
public delegate bool Predicate<in T>(T obj);
```

You can also use `Func<Question, bool>` or your own delegate type.

In my `QuestionnaireSource` class, I added the `Filter` property:

```
class QuestionnaireSource
{
    public Repository Repository { get; set; }

    public IDictionary<QuestionDifficulty, int> { get; set; }
    
    public Predicate<Question> Filter { get; set; }
}
```

Now I can pass a lambda expression such as the following:

```
question => question is ChoiceQuestion
```

Now I can filter more flexibly thanks to C#'s pattern matching with `is`.
I can configure it as following using the `AddSource()` method of `QuestionnaireBuilder` when building my questionnaire:

```
builder
    .AddSource(source => {
        source.Repository = repo1;

        source.Count[QuestionDifficulty.Easy] = 10;
        source.Count[QuestionDifficulty.Medium] = 7;
        source.Count[QuestionDifficulty.Hard] =  3;

        source.Filter = question => question is ChoiceQuestion  
    });
```

Now I can filter out or include multiple types:

```
question => question is ChoiceQuestion || question is ShortTextQuestion
```

Not only that, I can also filter using other criteria, such as the question text:

```
question => question.Text.Trim().StartsWith("What");
```

@benjamin's answer also works if you want to select just one subtype but this filter approach seems to be a bit more flexible if multiple types are to be selected or ignored.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to make your `PickOnlySpecificSubclassesOfQuestion` generic, and pass it one argument representing the type of question you want.

```
public void PickOnlySpecificSubclassesOfQuestion<T>()
where T : Question
```

Inside that method, you could get a System.Type representing the requested type of question like this:

```
Type desiredTypeOfQuestion = typeof(T);
```

Then, given an `IEnumerable` of questions containing questions of all different types,  you could use Linq and Reflection to find the ones that are assignable from the desired type:

```
return myQuestions.Where(q => q.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(desiredTypeOfQuestion));
```

I'm sure there are other approaches that would work too, but this is the one that sprang to mind most easily.

Comment: This is a nice solution when I want to work with questions of one subtype. I've ended up using a higher order function instead for a bit more flexibility(described in my answer). Thank you!